# Is there a way to configure OpenIddict Encryption Keys using Dependency Injection (to allow the use of secure vaults with DI)?

Tags: dependency-injection, access-token, azure-keyvault, openiddict

When configuring [OpenIddict](https://documentation.openiddict.com/index.html) encryption keys (both for signing and validating signed *"access tokens"*), this is done in the *Startup* of the application (`public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {...}`), where the services (DI) are still being registered.

So, assuming that the asymmetric keys I want to use to sign/validate the tokens are stored on **Azure Key Vault**, and in the context of following the good practices and principles (like SOLID) to use **Dependency Injection** to implement a *client* to access my Azure Key Vault (instead of a *static helper class* that can just be called in the `Startup`, as done in [this example](https://kevinchalet.com/2017/08/15/using-azure-key-vault-with-asos-and-openiddict/)), **my question is...**

***Is there a way to configure OpenIddict Encryption Keys using Dependency Injection, maybe using a function or handler that would be run after the setup is done?***

---

Example of configuring OpenIddict Server:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOpenIddict()
        // [...]
        .AddServer(options =>
        {
            // [...]
             var key = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey(rsaKey);
             options.AddSigningKey(key);
             // [...]
        });
}
```

Example of configuring a Resource API with OpenIddict validation:

```cs
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddOpenIddict()
        .AddValidation(options =>
        {   
            // [...]
            var key = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey(rsaKey);
            options.AddEncryptionKey(key);
            // [...]
        });
 }
```

The only way of using DI I found is **not recommended at all**, which would be registering the services I need first, and manually calling `services.BuildServiceProvider()` to have a `ServiceProvider` to resolve the type I need and its dependencies, example:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOpenIddict()
        // [...]
        .AddServer(options =>
        {
            // [...]
            ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var azureKeyVaultClient = serviceProvider.GetService<IAzureKeyVaultClient>();
            var rsaKey = azureKeyVaultClient.GetKey(myKeyName).ToRSA();

            var key = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey(rsaKey);
            options.AddSigningKey(key);
             // [...]
        });
}
```

But, as you can see below, besides the fact it is a very odd approach, it's also not recommended because *"Calling 'BuiIdServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created."*.
[image]

So, does anyone know how I can use DI when configuring OpenIddict keys?

Comment: is `IAzureKeyVaultClient` interface a custom class ? Is it define as a singleton ?

Comment: @Thomas `IAzureKeyVaultClient` is an example of a custom interface (to wrap Azure Key Vault Client) where there would be a custom implementation class for it, that could be registered as a singleton scope.

Comment: You could instantiate the class before registering it then you would still have access to it when configuring the openidict ?

Comment: Did you find a better solution by now? I have this same problem.